# Check Package exist or not before create it in Oracle

Tags: oracle, package, exists

Need help

How do I check for a package if it exists or not and skip the creation if it already exists.

I have done the following and I got an error

```
DECLARE
    l_cnt INTEGER;
    own   VARCHAR(200);
BEGIN
    SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ) INTO own FROM dual;
    SELECT count(*)
    INTO l_cnt
    FROM ALL_OBJECTS
    WHERE object_type = 'PACKAGE' 
    and object_name = 'JUSTICE_LEAGUE'
      AND OWNER        = own;
    IF( l_cnt       <= 0) THEN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 
'create or replace PACKAGE "JUSTICE_LEAGUE" AS

FUNCTION BATMAN(argPSN INT)
RETURN INT;

FUNCTION SUPERMAN(argSN int)
RETURN Info.infovalue%Type;

PROCEDURE AQUAMAN(argASN INT,argAssignedUser folderProcess.assignedUser%Type DEFAULT 'None');

END JUSTICE_LEAGUE';

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Package created successfully');
    ELSE
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Package exists already');

END IF;
END;
/

Error report -
ORA-06550: line 23, column 70:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ALL" when expecting one of the following:
```

Is it a right way to put the create command for package within EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ?

Comment: what is the reason you are creating dynamically,do you have to copy the package to other schemas ??

Answer (score 3):

First of all - no, it is wrong way to do that. The fact that dynamic SQL exists doesn't mean that you should use it, especially not for creating packages (or any other objects). There are really rare situations you'd want to do that.

PL/SQL procedures (functions, packages, triggers) offer create **OR REPLACE** option so - it is safe to run that statement *as is* (not as dynamic SQL). It means that:

- if it doesn't exist, it'll be created
- if it exists, it'll be *overwritten* by code you've just ran

If you insist on dynamic SQL, check its (package's) existence by querying `user_objects`:

```
SQL> select count(*)
  2  from user_objects
  3  where object_name = 'JUSTICE_LEAGUE'
  4    and object_type = 'PACKAGE';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         0

SQL>
```

Depending on result, run `execute immediate` (or not).

Comment: I Totally agree with you @Littlefoot, but this is that exceptional case where a lot of DB's have this Package available that have been customized as per there work.

I cannot overwrite there package but I can add if they dont have it with baselined package.

Comment: OK; then just run it with CREATE PACKAGE (i.e. omit REPLACE). If it exists, it'll fail and nothing (but) will happen. Why do you care if it fails? I mean - make it simple.

Comment: If I do so then the users executing the query will see the error and have a concern on why is there an error. DO u think there is a way to work that out.

I do the way you say and remove the `and Replace` part. What do i do to later the error that is raised.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one issue with your code.

You have not handled the dynamic query properly. single-quote in the dynamic query must be escaped.

Two single quotes(`''`) in the string are considered as one single quote(`'`) in the final string.
Or you can use the quoted-string (`q'{<your_string>}'`)

replace -- `DEFAULT 'None');` with `DEFAULT ''None'');`

Comment: what if i am adding a Package Body within the `Execute Immedtiade ' '`